# How Can I Index and Search with Elasticsearch

Tags: java, api, indexing, elasticsearch, response

```
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("face", "book","1")
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject()
                        .field("name", "kimchy")
                        .field("postDate", "2010-03-01")
                        .field("message", "trying out Elastic Search")
                        .endObject()
                )
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
String index = response.getIndex(); // index : "face"

SearchResponse r = client.prepareSearch("face")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name","kimchy"))
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
      System.out.println(r);
      SearchHit[] hits = r.getHits().getHits();
      System.out.println(hits.length); // 0 Hits
      for (SearchHit searchHit : hits) {
      // no hits no data
      }
```

How can I fix this , where is the problem here ? My each attempts gives 0 hits.I tried everything but i could not fix.I will be happy if someone help me to fix this code.If I write prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet","1") and client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet","1") it gives me some results but i think this is default result.I want to search specific word which i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
.setRefresh(true)
```

To your client.prepareIndex call

Comment: While this solution works, it implies that you should `refresh` your indices manually.  As I'm sure @mconlin knows but hasn't said, refreshing manually for testing purposes is fine, but would have a performance impact in production if done on every request. better to let Elasticsearch do it automatically in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that search works in near real-time, which means that a refresh needs to happen after you indexed a document in order for it to be available for search.

A refresh automatically happens every second by default, but in your test you need to either call refresh manually to make sure the document is found, or switch to using the get api, which works in real-time, to make sure the document is present, getting it back by id.

In case you add refresh, you can either call the refresh api or add the refresh flag to the index operation, so that a refresh will happen after the document is indexed. Just remember that this is good practice while testing, but in production your code shouldn't call refresh manually, just let the automatic refresh kick in every second.

Comment: Thnx for reply it did work .
So did you mean 
Indexing - Thread.sleep(60000) and
Search operation works fine ?
what is the unuseful side of manual refreshing ?

Comment: Thread.sleep works but is not that elegant... the downside of manually refreshing is performance, a new lucene segment gets flushed, if you index a lot of documents at the same time and you refresh after each index operation...well your throughput is going to suck :)

Comment: That said refreshing during testing is fine, in production just let the search be near real-time, that's it.

Comment: Ohh I understood,I work with big datas and as you said manually refresh operation slows down the project.I am new at elasticsearch, again thnx for your reply:)